# ¿Como comprobar si hay un numero dentro de un arreglo?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo este arreglo.Las letras se mueven solamente si la siguiente posicion es un cero y mi duda es como puedo comprobar si la siguiente posicion es un cero

//Parte de mi codigo

```
                System.out.println("¿A que numero desea moverla?");
                int posicioni = menu.nextInt();
                System.out.println("¿A que letra desea moverla?");
                int posicionj = menu.nextInt();

                b1 = posicioni;//Se le asigna a b1 la nueva posicion
                b2 = posicionj;//Se le asigna a b2 la nueva posicion


                for (i = 0; i < matriza.length; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < matriza.length; j++) {

                        System.out.print(matriza[i][j] + " ");
                        matriza[4][6] = "0";
                        matriza[b1][b2] = "r";

                    }

                    System.out.println("");
                }
                Mov++;//Contador para los movimientos
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con el método

```
Character.IsDigit(char);
```

Ese método devuelve `true` o `false` dependiendo de si el `char` que le pases por parámetro es un número o no.

En esta página tienes más información sobre este método:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_isdigit.htm

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un metodo que controle si el String ingresado es numerico o no

```
 public boolean isNumeric(String cadena) {

    boolean resultado;

    try {// se controla una posible excepcion
        Integer.parseInt(cadena);// si se logra guardar correctamente es un numero
        resultado = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException excepcion) {//si no se logra guardar correctamente ocurre lo siguente:
        resultado = false;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```